# Inquiry regarding the recommended number rules/policies for cloud Armor

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What's the recommended number of rules, policies, and incoming requests that can be provisioned for price estimates in Google Cloud Armor?[Price estimate calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmvJf.png)

Comment: Typically you would create one policy and as many rules as you require. I typically implement/enable 10 rules from the OWASP. For requests, that depends on how much traffic goes to your backends.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.